# how to add directory name after uri

Tags: 7, files, uri

I want to append the name of a directory, say 'abc' to `public://` uri of `sites/default/files` directory, such that it will point to the 'abc' directory inside `sites/default/files`.

Actually, whenever I try to do this `file_move($file_object, 'public://abc', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE)` it moves the file inside `sites/default/files` and creates a file called 'abc'.

I want to move the file inside 'abc' directory, by appending 'abc' to `public://`, how do I do this?

I have searched for this and found that `public://abc` does the trick, but its not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is telling drupal to move $file->filename to public://abc and hence renamed to abc. Drupal is doing what you are asking to do.

your $destination should be - 'public://abc/' . $file->filename

file_move($file, $destination, FILE_EXIST_REPLACE );

Below code should work (though not tested):

```
 $file = file_load($fid);
 $destination = 'public://abc/';
 if(file_prepare_directory($destination, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
   file_move($file, $destination . $file->filename, FILE_EXIST_REPLACE);
 }
```

Comment: appending file name to the destination gives error

Comment: can you pastebin your code? and whats the error that you are getting?

Comment: its same as I mentioned in the question, here you will find the details http://pastebin.com/JwjJbLJp

Comment: Can you specify the error in detail? Are you sure that the directory exist? why dont you use file_prepare_directory to check and see if it exist.

Comment: Try this - http://pastebin.com/5pyYDzSU

Comment: sorry my mistake the directory created didn't had enough permissions. thanks a lot :)